# API con Fetch "next page"

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch

Estoy probando con la API https://swapi.co/.

Lo hice con el **método fetch** y todo correcto, pero tengo una duda respecto a cargar más objetos, ya que los reparte en diferentes páginas como podéis ver aquí: https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json

Tiene next y previous, lo cual te va cargando a la siguiente página, y te mostrará los nuevos datos. ¿Podríais indicarme de que forma podría hacerlo y que me vaya mostrando las siguientes páginas?

Dejo el código aquí:

```
'use strict'

var personajes = document.querySelector(".personajes");

    getPersonajes()
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(people => {

                    listadoPersonajes(people.results);

                })
                .catch(error => {// CAPTURAR ERRORES Y EXCEPCIONES QUE OCURRAN EN EL CODIGO
                    console.log(error+ " Error en la peticion 1");
                })

    function getPersonajes() {
        return fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json')
    }

let pintarPersonajes = ``

function listadoPersonajes(usuarios){

    usuarios.map((user, i) => {// Recorremos los usuarios con los parametros users y su index(i)

        pintarPersonajes = `
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title name">${user.name}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text height">${user.height}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        `
        personajes.innerHTML += pintarPersonajes;

        document.querySelector(".loader").style.display = "none";
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    'use strict'

    var personajes = document.querySelector(".personajes");


    getPersonajes();
 
 // configuramos un valor por defecto para url en caso de que no se envie
    function getPersonajes(url){  // forma 1 getPersonajes(url='https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json'){ 
     // forma 2 "me gusta mas"
     url = url || 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json';

        fetch(url)
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(people => {
                listadoPersonajes(people.results);
             // operador !! convierte a booleano y && ejecuta lo que sigue
             // si lo anterior es true example: if(people.next){getPersonajes(people.next)}
             !!people.next &&  getPersonajes(people.next);
            })
            .catch(err => { // CAPTURAR ERRORES Y EXCEPCIONES QUE OCURRAN EN EL CODIGO
                console.log(err + " Error en la peticion 1");
            })

    }

    let pintarPersonajes = ``

    function listadoPersonajes(usuarios) {

        usuarios.map((user, i) => { // Recorremos los usuarios con los parametros users y su index(i)

            pintarPersonajes = `
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title name">${user.name}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text height">${user.height}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        `
            personajes.innerHTML += pintarPersonajes;

            //document.querySelector(".loader").style.display = "none";
        });

    }
```

```html
<div class="personajes"></div>
```

darle next con un click:

```js
  'use strict'

        var personajes = document.querySelector(".personajes");
        var nextUrl = null;
getPersonajes();
     
     
     // configuramos un valor por defecto para url en caso de que no se envie
        function getPersonajes(url){  // forma 1 getPersonajes(url='https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json'){ 
         // forma 2 "me gusta mas"
         url = url || 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json';

            fetch(url)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(people => {
                    listadoPersonajes(people.results);
                 // operador !! convierte a booleano y && ejecuta lo que sigue
                 // si lo anterior es true example: if(people.next){getPersonajes(people.next)}
                 nextUrl = !!people.next ? people.next: null;
                })
                .catch(err => { // CAPTURAR ERRORES Y EXCEPCIONES QUE OCURRAN EN EL CODIGO
                    console.log(err + " Error en la peticion 1");
                })

        }

        let pintarPersonajes = ``

        function listadoPersonajes(usuarios) {

            usuarios.map((user, i) => { // Recorremos los usuarios con los parametros users y su index(i)

                pintarPersonajes = `
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title name">${user.name}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text height">${user.height}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            `
                personajes.innerHTML += pintarPersonajes;

                //document.querySelector(".loader").style.display = "none";
            });

        }
        
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click",(e) =>{
  if(nextUrl)
      getPersonajes(nextUrl);
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">next</button>
<div class="personajes"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Bryno, funciona perfectamente. Una duda sobre eso, ¿Cómo lo podría hacer para cargar los datos cuando pulsara un botón "Next" y "Previous" ?

Comment: crea una variable en el scope global llamada `var nextUrl = null` y cambias `!!people.next &&  getPersonajes(people.next);` por un `nextUrl = !!people.next ?  people.next : null;` y ahora solo debes llamar a `getPersonajes(nextUrl)` cuando se de el evento click.

Comment: estoy intentando como me dijiste pero no me sale por alguna razón. ¿Podrías modificar la respuesta tuya para ver como se haría?

Comment: Mil gracias por tu ayuda @Bryro ! Funcionando :)